# Insertion Sort - How to accept input and print the sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm, insertion-sort

I was trying to do a Insertion Sort Program that accepts any Data Type (Int, Double, String) then print's the sorted array. I know that my code work's but i can't figure out the real problem.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyInsertionSort 

{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter anything you want");
        String insertionSort = in.nextLine(); 
        int num=Integer.parseInt(insertionSort);
        String array[] = new String [num];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Input the Number at array index "+i+": ");
            array[i] = in.nextLine();
        }

    public static void insertionSort(int array[]) 
    { 
        int n = array.length; 
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) 
        { 
            int key = array[j]; 
            int i = j-1; 
            while ( (i > -1) && ( array [i] > key ) ) 
            { 
                array [i+1] = array [i]; i--; 
            } 
            array[i+1] = key; 
            printNumbers(array); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this site is for answering problems not finding problems. Find what's wrong then we can answer it :s

Comment: You are missing a closing brace before `public static void insertionSort(int array[])`. You should learn to indent your code correctly, so that these errors are more obvious.

Comment: you should check out generic method with parameters or use method overloading since your code works..it will be easy i guess

Comment: This code has lot of errors like the main method does not call the method `insertionSort`

Comment: To add , You have not written any logic for sorting strings or double.

Comment: So, it's pretty clear that your code does _NOT_ work. So ask us a specific question. Where can we help?

Answer (score 0):

## Generic type Insertion Sort

I did a quick check and fixed all of the errors. Just compare your code and this one in a comparing tool. So that you can learn what you missed. This code is capable of doing sorting with Multiple data types like String, double, int as of now. It can be altered for any object that implements comparable.

Below is working code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyInsertionSort 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter data type to sort : ");
        String type = in.nextLine(); 

        System.out.print("Enter number of elements : ");
        String insertionSort = in.nextLine(); 
        int num=Integer.parseInt(insertionSort);
        String array[] = new String[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Input the Number at array index "+i+": ");
            array[i] = in.nextLine();
        }
        MyInsertionSort.insertionSortByType(array,type);
        in.close();
    }


    public static void insertionSortByType(String array[], String type)
    {
        switch (type) {
            case "double":
                Double[] ConvertedArrayDouble = new Double[array.length];
                for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) ConvertedArrayDouble[i] = Double.parseDouble(array[i]);
                MyInsertionSort.insertionSort(ConvertedArrayDouble);
                break;
            case "int":
                Integer[] ConvertedArrayInt = new Integer[array.length];
                for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) ConvertedArrayInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
                MyInsertionSort.insertionSort(ConvertedArrayInt);
                break;
            default:
                MyInsertionSort.insertionSort(array);   
        }
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void insertionSort(E array[]) 
    { 
        int n = array.length; 
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) 
        { 
            E key = array[j]; 
            int i = j-1; 
            while ( (i > -1) && ( array[i].compareTo(key) > 0 ) ) 
            { 
                array [i+1] = array [i]; i--; 
            } 
            array[i+1] = key; 
        }

        printNumbers(array); 
    }

    public static <E> void printNumbers(E array[]) {
        for (E i : array) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP says he wants to be able to take "any Data Type", but this code reads only `ints` (using `nextInt()`). He had problems, but you've taken this in a different direction.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I have updated my answer to take generic types as input and sort. Can you please check now?

Comment: You're putting a lot of effort into this. I respect that. As long as we know _in advance_ what kind of data the user wants to sort, i.e. the type of `array`, your approach looks sound.