# Java : Is there a way to know the type of primitive data in a string

Tags: java

I have a string array of the same primitive type (don't know what). I need to convert that into the corresponding type. Is there any way if I pass a string and get the primitive type of the data if any in that string. Consider the string is supposed to be having a primitive type or it is treated as String

For e-g

```
"5.2" - double
"5" - int (most related)
"s" - char
```

So that, if it is double, i can parse using `Double.parseDouble`

Comment: I would think about using regular expressions to determine the type.

Comment: You could either go with a more sophisticated version of slartidans answer (although using exceptions as flow-direction is considered bad style) or use regular expressions as JF Meier suggested (see Raphaels answer might be best suited). The problem might be, you need to test the whole array, since having `{0,0,0,c}` would test the whole array until you get type char. An easier solution would be, to store the type somewhere or using Generics (with the boxed type).

Comment: `5` could be a byte, char, short, int, long, float or double.  You have to make assumptions about what it is.  YAML for example, assumes it's an integer but you have to decide if its an `int`, `long` or `BigInteger`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not possible. For example this input:

```
5
```

- This could be an **int**
- But it could also be a **byte**, **short** or **long**
- It could as well be a **float** or a **double**
- It could even be a **char**

The only thing we know about it is, that it is probably not a **boolean**.

---

You could of course also try to parse your string like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkType("5.2");
    checkType("5");
    checkType("s");
}

protected static void checkType(String input) {
    System.out.println(input);
    try {
        byte result = Byte.parseByte(input);
        System.out.println("could be interpreted as byte "+result);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("not an byte");
    }
    try {
        short result = Short.parseShort(input);
        System.out.println("could be interpreted as short "+result);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("not an short");
    }
    try {
        int result = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println("could be interpreted as int "+result);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("not an int");
    }
    try {
        long result = Long.parseLong(input);
        System.out.println("could be interpreted as long "+result);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("not an long");
    }
    try {
        float result = Float.parseFloat(input);
        System.out.println("could be interpreted as float "+result);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("not an float");
    }
    try {
        double result = Double.parseDouble(input);
        System.out.println("could be interpreted as double "+result);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("not an double");
    }
    try {
        boolean result = Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
        System.out.println("could be interpreted as boolean "+result);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("not a boolean");
    }
    if (input.length() == 1) {
        System.out.println("could be interpreted as character "+input);
    } else {
        System.out.println("not a character");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

For the given examples, it outputs:

```
5.2
not an byte
not an short
not an int
not an long
could be interpreted as float 5.2
could be interpreted as double 5.2
could be interpreted as boolean false
not a character

5
could be interpreted as byte 5
could be interpreted as short 5
could be interpreted as int 5
could be interpreted as long 5
could be interpreted as float 5.0
could be interpreted as double 5.0
could be interpreted as boolean false
could be interpreted as character 5

s
not an byte
not an short
not an int
not an long
not an float
not an double
could be interpreted as boolean false
could be interpreted as character s
```

Comment: The need is that I have a string array of the same primitive type (don't know what). I need to convert that into the corresponding type

Comment: @Thanga in those cases it *usually* is not necessary to *parse* the items. What do you want to do with the values? Just printing them out? Or sum them together?

Comment: It could need to be a BigInteger or BigDecimal depending on context. +1

Comment: @slartidan I want to use it in a generic insertion sort program in  my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35629991/5678086

Comment: @Thanga You should use a generic <T extends Number> method in your solution and the method `valueOf(String)`. That way you dont have to save type in a String.

Answer (score 2):

You can't guess automatically the content of a `String` but if you have a set of rules, you can create a method to parse the content.

Write an `Identifier` class that can identify the type of a `String` and then call the associated parser to retrieve the primitive value.

Here is a small set of regex that matches your question:

- `double` = regex: `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$`, parser: `Double.parseDouble(String)`
- `int` = regex: `^[0-9]+$`, parser: `Integer.parseInt(String)`
- `char` = regex: `^[a-zA-Z]$`, parser: `value.charAt(0)`

Side note: this set of regex does not handle negative values. Also, don't forget to check for `NumberFormatException` when using `parseInt` and `parseDouble`.

Comment: Primitive types can contain much more. Regular Expressions could be the solution that Thanga is looking for, but *exact* parsing is much more difficult (all primitive numbers are allowed to contain `_`s in Java, their size is limited, negative numbers are allowed, numbers do not have to be decimals - but can be hex, binary, etc.)

Comment: I agree. If the purpose is to retrieve the ''exact'' primitive value then this solution won't work. However, to me, It does not feels like he really needs that.

Answer (score 0):

Java Strings are abstractions for characters and see nothing but characters.

The String itself does not know what kind of representations are inside of it, other than that it is all a homogeneous(exclusive to) collection of characters.

If you are being mislead by the "+" operator. This operator condenses what you are *concatenating* to the object, and as the object is concatenated, it is converted to a string of characters, so your data is indeed lost.

You will need to analyze the string yourself to decide if it contains information meaningful to you and extract it.

It is possible to create your own string that is capable of storing such information, but it bloats the construct, since you rarely need to use such features, and they may as well be used externally.

It would be more helpful to post what you are trying to accomplish instead of abstract possibility claim. To which the answer is yes, you can do  that, but the string will not help you do it, you will need to parse the string yourself.

See "http://asciivalue.com/" to see that any string you enter essentially hides away this data almost exclusively(as well as a terminating 0 usually). If it had to store the data you are asking in your question, it would be too expensive to store.